# How to connect external chat web application to Microsoft Teams chats?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

My company has a platform that connects all type of chat channels like WhatsApp, Viber, Line, FB messenger and others. By adding the channels the users in our platform able to chat directly with users on the channels.

So we would like to know if we able to connect our platform to MS Teams chat users and chat directly from our platform.

I'm not sure how we can connect from our platform to MS Teams.
Found below articles but these don't point out what need to be done exactly.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Answer (score 0):

Webhooks help Microsoft Teams to integrate with external apps. In Teams, the Outgoing Webhooks act as bot and search for messages in channels using @mention. The Outgoing Webhooks allow users to send messages to web services without performing the entire process of creating bots through Microsoft Bot Framework. The Outgoing Webhooks post data from Teams to any service capable of accepting JSON payload.The service responds within ten seconds to the message with a text or a card.

Ref Doc:-1.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-outgoing-webhook?tabs=urljsonpayload%2Cdotnet

2.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/sbs-outgoing-webhooks

Comment: Hi Sayali.. Thanks for the answer.. This is more like a chat bot I guess.. I'm looking for a 2way interaction between MS Teams user and a user(an agent) from platform..

Comment: I would like to have a similar setup of how Skype and Teams users able to chat directly.. It'll be great if I can a documentation on this setup.. Hope someone can help me out..

Comment: here is related thread -https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/teams-unable-to-chat-with-external-users/1503517e-f915-4dfa-9025-d32604f68d73
hope it's helpful.

Comment: Hi Sayali.. That never help actually.. thanks for trying though..

Comment: This question is being tracked here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72297772/connect-microsoft-teams-chat-with-other-chat-service